# List of resource names which shouldn't be used to Avoid not a valid Identifier warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I gave a try to find a consolidated list of identifiers which one shouldn't use while creating resource names, but couldn't find one.

Please provide a list of identifiers which one should not use.

I learned that Visual Studio throws warning for identifiers like hyphens(-), dot(.), but as I mentioned I do not have a full list.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this topic, but if i modify the default resouce file in visual studio i get this warning(f.e. with spaces or dots). But if i programmatically add resousces i can use whatever i want as name. `using (var resx = new ResXResourceWriter(@"ResourcesTest.resx"))
            {
                resx.AddResource("1 2", "Bah");
            } `

Comment: @Robert Harvey please suggest, if the edit still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the generated `Resource.Designer.cs`, you will see that the resource key is used as property name.

For example the Key "AddUser" is implemented like this:

```
/// <summary>
///   Looks up a localized string similar to Add User.
/// </summary>
public static string AddUser {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("AddUser", resourceCulture);
    }
 }
```

Therefore, the resource key must adhere to the C# spec for [Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx).

(Compare with the spec for [Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04(VS.71).aspx): `[attributes] [modifiers] type identifier {accessor-declaration}`)